# How can two specs share the same "it" block?

Tags: ruby, rspec-rails

I have two tests that are very similar. In fact, both tests should produce the same results, but for different inputs. Each needs its own `before` block but in the interest of DRY I'd like them to share the same `it` block.

Is that even possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helper methods. (Excuse the horribleness of the example. Would have been better if you'd posted yours :P)

```
describe "soup" do
  def soup_is_salty        # helper method! \o/
    soup.add(:meat)
    soup.add(:egg)
    soup.cook
    soup.salty?
  end

  describe "with carrot" do
    before(:all) do
      soup.add(:carrot)
    end

    it "should be salty" do
      soup_is_salty        # get help from helper method! \o/
    end
  end

  describe "soup with potato" do
    before(:all) do
      soup.add(:potato)
    end

    it "should be salty" do
      soup_is_salty        # get help from helper method! \o/
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Shared Examples in Rspec are designed to be used for this purpose. You can keep common `it` blocks inside a shared example and include them in describe or context blocks.

Simplest example of shared_examples would be,

```
RSpec.shared_examples "unauthorized_response_examples" do
  it {  expect(subject).to respond_with(403) }
  it {  expect(json['message']).to eq(I18n.t("unauthorized")) }
end
```

And inside your controller specs whenever you need to check unauthorized response you can include examples like,

```
...
include_examples "unauthorized_response_examples"
```

Also,  you can pass on parameters, action names and controller names and have `before(:each|:all)` hooks and nested `contexts` or `describe`.

For more, you can look at [rspec documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples).

Answer (score 1):

Take the block and create and external method

for example I have some tests that require me to login to my app. So I have a `helper.rb` file that I include in each spec and that contains a "login" block. Then in each test I can just call `login`